# Youtube videos not played in Electron app but in a website does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, youtube, electron

I'm working on two related projects, a web page and an application in Electron, among other things, both have to play Youtube videos embedded in an iframe. Everything works perfectly on the website,

```
var newUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $scope.youtube_parser(video.url);
        $scope.videoURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(newUrl + '?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0');
$scope.setYTPlayer();

$scope.setYTPlayer = function(){
    $scope.player;
    $scope.player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: $scope.videoSelected,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ng-src="{{videoURL}}" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

but in the Electron application many of the videos are not played, a message is read on the player: "video not available"

```
var youtubeId = $scope.getYoutubeId(video.url)
    $scope.currentVideo = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(
      'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId + '?rel=0'
    )
<iframe width="100%" height="442" ng-src="{{ currentVideo }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[Capture of the player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TPuS.png)

The same link, with the same method, on the page reproduces without any problem. Try with the iframe only, with the api, changing the playback parameters and the problem continues.
The question is, is there any Youtube policy that does not allow videos to be played in certain places? Or what can be the error?

Electron versión: v3.0.3

Thanks and apologies if I can not express myself well.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far. In your case I would recommend to go through the electron docs and tutorials in regards to embedding yt-videos and try to grasp the general approach for what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If some play and some not then it depends on the content usage restrictions of the Video on YT where you can forbid embedding for example.

Answer (score 4):

This problem appears due to the protocol through which you open the electron window.
If you open a local html file, then "file://" protocol is used.I found 2 solutions to this problem:

> You can raise a local temporary http server to transfer the html file for the window, and then disable it.

```
import http from 'http';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

//at start
let server;
server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
const filePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'public', req.url);
const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
res.end(file.toString());
if (req.url.includes('index.js'))
   server.close();
}).listen(8080);

//after app-ready event
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/index.html');
```

> A more preferable option is to intercept the http protocol and transfer files, but you must disable interception after transferring all local files, otherwise it will affect all subsequent http requests.

```
import path from 'path';

//before window.loadURL
session.defaultSession.protocol.interceptFileProtocol('http', (request, callback) => {
    const fileUrl = request.url.replace('http://localhost/', '');
    const filePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'public', fileUrl);

    if(request.url.includes('index.js')) {
        session.defaultSession.protocol.uninterceptProtocol('http');
    }
    callback(filePath);
});
//after app-ready event
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/index.html');
```

> Also, if you get an error with the header "x-frame-options" = "sameorigin", you can delete this header after receiving a response.

```
const filter = {
    urls: ['https://www.youtube.com/*']
};
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived(filter, (details, callback) => {
    for (const header in details.responseHeaders) {
        if (header.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'x-frame-options') {
            delete details.responseHeaders[header];
        }
    }
    callback({ cancel: false, responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders });
});
```

Comment: it just loads empty window for me